# How to fix Blackfire profiling error when using with Docker Compose?

Tags: php, docker, blackfire

My app runs with Docker in development mode thanks to a docker-compose.yml file.

I installed Blackfire following to the letter the [Docker doc](https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/docker) and the [PHP Probe doc](https://blackfire.io/docs/php/integrations/php-docker).

I have the Firefox add-on installed in my browser.

When trying to profile my page (http://localhost) I get the following error:

> Are You Authorized to Profile this Page? Probe Not Found or Invalid signature.

I followed what's indicated in the [Troubleshooting](https://support.blackfire.io/en/articles/233599-are-you-authorized-to-profile-this-page-probe-not-found-or-invalid-signature) to try and fix the errors:

- The agent is running
- The probe is properly installed and enabled (I see it when running `php -m` in my php container)
- The env variables (client & server id/token) are recognized by the blackfire container

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation about [installing Blackfire with Docker](https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/docker) in a docker-compose.yml file, the given port in the ports option is 8***3***07.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  blackfire:
    image: blackfire/blackfire:2
    ports: ["8307"]
    environment:
        # Exposes BLACKFIRE_* environment variables from the host
        BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID: ~
        BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN: ~
        BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID: ~
        BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN: ~
```

In the documentation about [enabling the PHP Probe with Docker](https://blackfire.io/docs/php/integrations/php-docker), the given port in both Linux image and Alpine image is 8***7***07 (see second to last line starting with `&& printf "extension=blackfire.so`). Below the example for Linux Image:

```sh
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN version=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") \
    && architecture=$(case $(uname -m) in i386 | i686 | x86) echo "i386" ;; x86_64 | amd64) echo "amd64" ;; aarch64 | arm64 | armv8) echo "arm64" ;; *) echo "amd64" ;; esac) \
    && curl -A "Docker" -o /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -D - -L -s https://blackfire.io/api/v1/releases/probe/php/linux/$architecture/$version \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/blackfire \
    && tar zxpf /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -C /tmp/blackfire \
    && mv /tmp/blackfire/blackfire-*.so $(php -r "echo ini_get ('extension_dir');")/blackfire.so \
    && printf "extension=blackfire.so\nblackfire.agent_socket=tcp://blackfire:8707\n" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/blackfire.ini \
    && rm -rf /tmp/blackfire /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz
```

You should change one or the other port to have the same one at the two places. Then restart your containers.

---

**Edit:** The error has been fixed.